# If $a_i$ are not necessarily distinct real & $1<a_i<13$ for all $i$.Show that we can choose three of them such that they are lengths of a triangle

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, triangles

> If $a_1,a_2,...a_7$ are not necessarily distinct real numbers such that $1<a_i<13$ for all $i$  .
>
> Show that we can choose three of them such that they are lengths of a triangle

I tried to solve this problem in the following steps:

Using the principle:

Sum of length of two sides > Length of third side

1. Sort all the $a_i$s in non descending order.
2. Observe that if $a_i,a_{i+1},a_{i+2}$ do not form a non-degenerate triangle,then $a_i+a_{i+1}\le a_{i+2} \implies$ as $ a_i$s are all sorted,then $a_{i-1}\le a_i \implies a_{i-1}+a_{i+1}\le a_{i+2}\implies$ $a_{i-1},a_{i+1}, a_{i+2}$ do not form a non-degenerate triangle.Again $a_i+a_{i+1}\le a_{i+2}\implies a_i+a_{i+1}\le a_{i+3}$. Thus $a_i,a_{i+1}, a_{i+3}$ do not form a non-degenerate triangle.

Now what should be my next step?Please help.

Comment: Well, if the numbers were $1,1,2,3,5,8,13,$ you couldn't form a triangle. I think you should try to prove that if $k_n$ is the smallest real number such that $1<a_i<k_n, \space 1\le i\le n$ guarantees that it is possible to choose $3$ of the $a_i$ that form a triangle, then $k_n$ is that $n$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: @saulspatz what a brilliant observation. It is a Fibonacci series. That alone is a brilliant observation. 1000+ votes for that.

Comment: @saulspatz you write it down as an answer . This alone is sufficient. I will accept it. I have got my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if the numbers were $1,1,2,3,5,8,13,$ you couldn't form a triangle. I think you should try to prove that if $k_n$ is the smallest real number such that $1<a_i<k_n, 1\le i\le n$ guarantees that it is possible to choose $3$ of the $a_i$ that form a triangle, then $k_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

**EDIT**

While you were kind enough to say this is a brilliant observation, it isn't so.  If it were, I couldn't have made it.  I just made small examples.  What is the bound for $3$ numbers?  For $4$ numbers?  Then I saw the pattern.

Comment: but I was thinking along the lines of triangle inequality wherein lied my hindrance.

Comment: @Saradamani The triangle inequality is obviously pertinent.  I'm just saying that you should try to make examples when you can't see what to do.  Textbook proofs often make it seem like the argument just suggested itself through some kind of divine inspiration, but in fact, mathematicians spend a lot of time making simple examples and trying to figure out what is going on.